# Power Amplifier Design using MRF136

Tags: amplifier, inductor

Currently, I am designing a Power Amplifier to driver an acousto-optic modulator which will be used in an optical experiment.

I want to get a 4W Sinusodial Wave, So I Choose the MA-COM's MRF136 as the last stage Power Amplifier. I refer to the datasheets of [MRF136](https://cdn.macom.com/datasheets/MRF136.pdf).

I found that the figure 1 in MRF136's datasheet provides us with the 150MHz test circuit, but with no accurate Capacitor or Inductor Values. For example, the  figure 1 in MRF136's datasheet  puts that L1 -- 2Turns, 0.29" ID, #18 AWG, 0.10" LONG.

[1]How can I calculate the exact value of the Inductor provided in the official test circuit in the datasheet, and purchase the proper RF inductor in the CoilCraft Corporation?

[2]Or Should I just put the official test circuit aside, and JUST simulate the S-parements in the Keysight's ADS software to get the proper Inductor's values?

[3]I thought that if I could reproduce the curves of the MRF136's official test circuit in the Keysight's ADS software, I can get an better understanding of the Power Amplifier Design.

Comment: Please post a schematic, if you edit your question there is a button that you can use to draw them.

Comment: I quote the Figure 1 of the datasheet of MRF136. And I struggle to draw the circuit, but I found that, it seems that there is no trimmer capacitor symbol. Thank you for your edtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found that the figure 1 in MRF136's datasheet provides us with the
>   150MHz test circuit, but with no accurate Capacitor or Inductor
>   Values.

[image]

Unless I'm missing something, all the capacitor values seem to be stated below the picture.

> L1 -- 2Turns, 0.29" ID, #18 AWG, 0.10" LONG

This will be an air-cored inductor and there are several calculators on-line for getting the inductance value. For instance [**this**](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Air-Core-Inductor-Calculator.phtml) calculator tells me that the inductance of L1 is 0.03649 uH: -

[image]

Note that the coil diameter should take into account the wire gauge hence the figure it needs is internal diameter plus one wire thickness. I didn't do that in the picture above.

[THIS](http://www.calculatoredge.com/new/Air%20Core%20Inductor%20Inductance.htm) calculator also comes up with the same value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Firstly, I mean that The Arco Trimmer Capacitor may vary in different situations , without accurate value.  Secondly, Your explanation of the Calculation of the inductors are what I need. Thanks again. I have already accept your answer. And If you can provide the

Comment: I am sorry.  I didn't finish the comment but I can not edit it now.

Comment: You can write a new comment if there is some supplementary question.

Comment: The MRF136Y is the push-pull configuration of the MRF136.

And the figure 1 of the [MRF136Y's datasheet](https://cdn.macom.com/datasheets/MRF136Y.pdf) also provides a test circuit. 

For I am not familiar with the transformer, how can I get the inductor of the Primary and Secondly windinds?  Or What matters in the Transformer.

For example, The Figure1 puts that, T1 -- Primary Windinds -- 3 Turns #28 Enameled Wire.  --Secondly Winding -- 2Turns #28 Enamelled Wire. Both windings wound through a Fair/Rite Balun 65 Core. Part #2865002402

Comment: I think if you can find the data sheets for the cores they will give a relationship between nH and turns noting that if you double the turns the inductance squares so, if they give you the inductance of 1 turn and you have 3 turns, the inductance increases 9 times. You can also assume primary and secondary are 95% coupled too.